# JqGrid. Получение названий колонок в связке с ячейкой

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Добрый день.
Я пытаюсь реализовать проверку заполненности данных с выводом ошибки, в которой описывается, какие именно ячейки не были заполнены в строке.

```
//получаем id Записи
var gr = $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
// проверяем, выбрана ли строка
if (gr != null) {
/*
var myGrid = $("#" + subgrid_table_id),
selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
//получаем содержимое ячейки:
col1Value = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'stage');
//Получаем массив названий колонок
var columnNames =  myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colNames');
//получаем название колонки, лишь зная ее индекс:
var col1Name = columnNames[4];
//Обрабатываем условие
if (col1Value == "")    {
    alert("Вы не заполнили колонку"+col1Name);
}
else {
```

То есть все вроде бы работает но при изменении количества колонок все может пойти прахом.
Как можно увязать название колонки в ColNames с ее названием в ColModel, чтобы получить динамическое решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы используете [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), то `iColByName` позволяет получить индекс по имени солонки.

```
//получаем содержимое ячейки:
var col1Value = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'stage');
//получаем 
var p = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam');
//получаем индекс колонки
var iCol = p.iColByName.stage; // или p.iColByName['stage']
//получаем название (заголовок) колонки, зная ее индекс:
var col1Name = p.colNames[iCol];
//получаем полное отисание колонки
var cm = p.colModel[iCol];
```

Если же Вы используете ретор версию jqGrid и по ряду причин Вы не можите сделать апгрейд на free jqGrid 4.14.0, то вместо `iColByName` (вместо `p.iColByName.stage`) придется использовать что-то вроде

```
var i, iCol = -1, cmName = 'stage';
for (i = 0; i < p.colModel.length; i++) {
    if (p.colModel[i].name === cmName) {
        iCol = i;
        break;
    }
}
// теперь можно использовать iCol - индекс колонки
```